# C# Invoke with out parameter using .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5, invoke

I want to invoke a function with two `out` parameters and `bool` as return value. Now my problem is I see that those two parameters are changed when I debug, but still they are back to length = 0 (the way they are initialized) when the function returns.

I've seen that there's a great solution for the .net-framework 4, but unfortunaly I have to use the .net-framework 3.5.

Here's my code:

```
public delegate bool GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate(out int[] cTypes, out int[] cFiles);
public bool GetAllCheckedItems(out int[] cTypes , out int[] cFiles ) 
{  
    if (ListView.InvokeRequired)
    {
         cTypes = new int[0];
         cFiles = new int[0];
         return (bool)ListView.Invoke(new GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate(GetAllCheckedItems), new object[] { cTypes, cFiles });
    }
    else
    {
       cTypes = new int[ListView.CheckedItems.Count];
       cFiles = new int[ListView.CheckedItems.Count];
       for (int i = 0; i < ListView.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
       {
             // ......code......
       }
       return (ListView.CheckedItems.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using that kind of invoking instead of just firing GetAllCheckedItems recursively?

Comment: I really think you need to rethink your approach here. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The function is called from a different thread so I have to invoke it. The function itself returns two arrays (and a bool value).

Comment: That invoke pattern is only really needed when interacting with UI components on the main UI thread. The above simply creates some arrays. What makes you think you need to use invoke?

Comment: Can you post some code what you would recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really like "out" keyword, so what about of using a class (Row) that contains information:

```
using SCG = System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class Row {
   public int CheckedType { get; set; }
   public int CheckedFile { get; set; }
}
...
public delegate SCG.IEnumerable<Row> GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate();
public bool GetAllCheckedItems() {  
   if (ListView.InvokeRequired) {
      var rows = ListView.Invoke(new GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate(GetAllCheckedItems)
            , new object[] {});
      return rows.Count() > 0;
   } else {
      var rows = new SCG.List<Row>();
      for (int i = 0; i < ListView.CheckedItems.Count; i++) {
         // create and set row 
         var row = new Row { CheckedType = x, CheckedFile = y };
         ...
         rows.Add(row);
      }
      return rows.AsReadOnly(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't like the out keyword, too. Something like this is what I was hoping for. I'll check if your code works as soon as possible (probably Monday) and if it works (what I'm pretty sure about) I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
     return (bool)ListView.Invoke(..., new object[] { cTypes, cFiles });
```

That modifies the object[] elements.  C# does not provide syntax to get it to update the arguments of the method, there's an extra level of indirection that you can't bridge with code.  It is up to you to copy the references back.  Nothing to worry about, you are not actually copying the array content, just the references:

```
var args = new object[] { null, null };
var dlg = new GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate(GetAllCheckedItems);
var retval = (bool)ListView.Invoke(dlg, args);
cTypes = (int[])args[0];
cFiles = (int[])args[1];
return retval;
```

Nothing pretty about it of course.  Do keep in mind that you are certainly doing something very unpretty, you have no guarantee whatsoever that you get the items you expect to get.  This code runs at a very unpredictable moment in time, quite disjoint from the code that's running on the UI thread.  If the user is busy checking items while the worker is running then you get a quite random selection.  A snapshot of the list box state that very quickly turns stale.

This almost always requires you to disable the list box while the worker is running so you provide a guarantee that the result you compute matches the list.  That in turn means that it is no longer useful to write this code at all, you might as well obtain the list *before* you start the thread.  Which is the real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that works for me. Still I'm open to different (and better) approaches if you think that this is not a good way to solve this.

```
public delegate bool BoolDelegate();    
public bool GetAllCheckedItems(out int[] cTypes , out int[] cFiles ) 
{
    if (ListView.InvokeRequired)
    {
          int[] cTypesHelpVar = new int[0];
          int[] cFilesHelpVar = new int[0];

          bool ret = (bool)ListView.Invoke((BoolDelegate) (() => GetAllCheckedItems(out cTypesHelpVar, out cFilesHelpVar)));

          cTypes = cTypesHelpVar;
          cFiles = cFilesHelpVar;

          return ret;
    }
    else
    {
          cTypes = new int[ListView.CheckedItems.Count];
          cFiles = new int[ListView.CheckedItems.Count];
          for (int i = 0; i < ListView.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
          {
                //.... code ....
          }
          return (ListView.CheckedItems.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how you use it in code. You created a delegate `GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate` and then you: `GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate delegate1 = new GetAllCheckedItemsDelegate(GetAllCheckedItems);`  ? and you can not receive correct parameters in `out` values ? Please refactor this code if possible - it obvious that this function returning some state: `bool`, `int[]` and `int[]` - so you could refactor it to some `struct` and return it as logical state. It will help you debug and use in multithreading scenarious.